# CSV writerow not writing the csv in order from api request, how can I write in the order want?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am building a script that requests data from a restapi and write the data to a csv file.
After some extensive testing I came to the realisation that the writerow won't write in the order I want him to write.

This is the script:

```
import csv
import requests
import json

from collections import OrderedDict


with open('Output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    f = csv.writer(csvfile)
    f.writerow(["asn", "name", "descr", "naughty_rating"])


data = "as.txt"
with open(data) as ad:
    line = ad.readline()
    while line:
        number = ''.join(c for c in line if c not in 'AS')
        url = "https://url.to-api.com/api/asns/" + number
        user = 'user'
        passwd = 'password'
        auth_values = (user, passwd)
        response = requests.get(url, data=data, auth=auth_values, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        info = response.json(object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

        with open('Output.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
            f = csv.writer(csvfile)
            f.writerow({info['asn'], info['name'], info['descr'], info['naughty_rating']})
```

In the as.txt is a list of number which need to be requested from the api one by one.
Every number gives a different values from the same json data. I want to structure that data into a csv file.

I hoped it would write in this order -> asn -> name -> descr -> naughty_rating.
It just doesn't.. Every line is written in a different order. I can't seem to get it to write in this exact order.

Would I have to make a ordered list before the writerow or something?
I was also thinking to first writing the json data to a .json file and after all the different request queries are done it will get the right data from the json file, but I think it should be possible to write to the csv directly after it requests from the api.

Comment: Replace the `{...}` in `.writerow({...}` with `(...)` or ` [...]` or use `csv.,DictWriter`

Comment: Aaah, thanks the replacement of {} with () worked!

Answer (score 1):

I had to change

```
f.writerow({info['asn'], info['name'], info['descr'], info['naughty_rating']})
```

to

```
f.writerow((info['asn'], info['name'], info['descr'], info['naughty_rating']))
```